# Make Id only visible for logged in wordpress admin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, element, display

I would like the following function to work, but not for the Wordpress Administrator.

`document.getElementById("my_id").style.display = 'none';`

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not require javascript for that.

If you are logged in as an admin. WordPress will add `logged-in admin-bar` classes to the body element. You can use this to change the display value in your `style.css` to hide elements.

```css
#my-id {
  display: none;
}

body.logged-in.admin-bar #my-id {
  /* Admin is logged in */
  display: block;
}
```

The order is important!

If you want to use javascript. Use PHP to check if the user is admin or not and write the javascript to the document. Add for example on `index.php`:

```php
<?php if( !current_user_can('editor') || !current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?>
    <script>/* Will be there if user is not admin or editor */</script>
<?php } ?>
```

You can combine this with an else statement.